# "Fluent interfaces" that maintain order in the invokation chain

Tags: oop

Is there an elegant/convinient way (without creating many "empty" classes or at least they should be not annoying) to have fluent interfcaes that maintain order on compilation level.

Fluent interfaces:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

with an idea to permit this compilation

```
var fluentConfig = new ConfigurationFluent().SetColor("blue")
                                           .SetHeight(1)
                                           .SetLength(2)
                                           .SetDepth(3);
```

and decline this

```
var fluentConfig = new ConfigurationFluent().SetLength(2)
                                           .SetColor("blue")
                                           .SetHeight(1)
                                           .SetDepth(3);
```

Comment: Also, this looks like a very language-dependent issue.  What language were you thinking of?  C#?

Comment: generally I'm looking for "language feature" in any language. "call order validation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a set of three ways of doing this in C++ using essentially a compile time FSM to validate the actions. You can find the [code on github](https://github.com/mikeando/Fluent-Interface-Test).

Comment: Super! Could I ask you to explain how you inject this into compilation process?

Comment: Each of the C++ files can be compiled stand-alone, but they still contain a lot more boiler-plate code than I'd like. So I've added an example using a fluent C++ interface in the same vein, but where the interface is defined by a simple conf file, and python is used to generate the .h and .cpp files. I suspect that is more appropriate for "real" usage.

Comment: Got it! The moral is: just don't afraid to generate code from code.

Answer (score 8):

Each step in the chain needs to return an interface or class that only includes the methods that are valid to use after the current step. In other words, if SetColor must come first, `ConfigurationFluent` should only have a SetColor method. SetColor would then return an object that only has a SetHeight method, and so forth.

In reality, the return values could all be the same instance of `ConfigurationFluent` but cast to different interfaces explicitly implemented by that class.

Comment: This is the solution. I implemented something similar using indexers a while back (http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2008/02/26/avoiding-overload-hell-in-c/) and it worked exactly as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, there is no elegant or convenient way to enforce an order of constructing a class that properly impelemnts the "Fluent Interface" as you've linked.

The longer answer starts with playing devil's advocate.  If I had dependent properties (i.e. properties that required other properties to be set first), then I could implement them something like this:

```
method SetLength(int millimeters)
    if color is null throw new ValidationException

    length = millimeters
    return this
end
```

(NOTE: the above does not map to any real language, it is just psuedocode)

So now I have exceptions to worry about.  If I don't obey the rules, the fluent object will throw an exception.  Now let's say I have a declaration like yours:

```
var config = new Fluent().SetLength(2).SetHeight(1).SetDepth(3).SetColor("blue");
```

When I catch the `ValidationException` because length depends on the color being set first, how am I as the user supposed to know what the correct order is?  Even if I had each `SetX` method on a different line, the stacktrace will just give me the line where the `config` variable was declared in most languages.  Furthermore, how am I supposed to keep the rules of this object straight in my head compared to other objects?  It is a cocophony of conflicting ideals.

Such precedence checks violate the spirit of the "Fluent Interface" approach.  That approach was designed for conveniently configure complex objects.  You take the convenience out when you attempt to enforce order.

To properly and elegantly implement the fluent interface there are a couple of guidelines that are best observed to make consumers of your class thank you:

- Provide meaningful default values: minimizes need to change values, and minimizes chances of creating an invalid object.
- Do not perform configuration validation until explicitly asked to do so.  That event can be when we use the configuration to create a new fully configured object, or when the consumer explicitly calls a `Validate()` method.
- In any exceptions thrown, make sure the error message is clear and points out any inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the compiler could check that methods are called in  the same order as they are defined.

this could be a new feature for compilers.

Or maybe by means of annotations, something like:

```
class ConfigurationFluent {

 @Called-before SetHeight
 SetColor(..)  {}

 @Called-After SetColor
 SetHeight(..) {}

 @Called-After SetHeight
 SetLength(..){ }

 @Called-After SetLength             
 SetDepth(..) {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a state machine of valid sequence of operations and on each method call the state machine and verify if the sequence of operation is allowed or throw an exception if not.
I will not suggest this approach for Configurations though, it can get very messy and not readable

Comment: What Joel Mueller is purposing is also the state machine.